# Ignore specific rows when updating in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to develop a website using `asp.net mvc 4` & `EF6` where I want to update multiple rows at once. So far everything is working fine but when I ignore the fields from view which will also be updated, I get `NullReferenceException` error when I try to update. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DueCheck(FlatModel DueLists)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var BillId in DueLists.BillCollection)
                {
                    var dbRentSchedule = db.BillChecks.Where(p => p.billid == BillId.billid).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (dbRentSchedule != null)
                    {
                        dbRentSchedule.isRented = BillId.isRented;
                        if (BillId.isRented == "Y")
                        {
                            dbRentSchedule.isFull = "Y";
                            dbRentSchedule.due = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("DueError");
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("DueCheck");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("DueError");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DueCheck", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BillCollection.Count; i++ )
    {
        if(Model.BillCollection[i].fullname != "N/A" && Model.BillCollection[i].isFull != "Y")    //If I remove the second condition then it works but will also show the records which is not needed.
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BillCollection[i].name)</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BillCollection[i].billid)@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BillCollection[i].due)</td>
                <td><div class="isFull btn btn-info">Approve</div>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BillCollection[i].isRented, new { @class = "assignFull" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" />
}
```

If I remove the condition `Model.BillCollection[i].isFull != "Y"` from view then it works perfectly but it'll also show unnecessary records which makes my system meaningless. How can I ignore those records from the server side instead of client side? Need this help badly. Tnx.

**UPDATE**

**BillCheck Model(EF6 generated)**

```
public partial class BillCheck
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string isRented { get; set; }
    public string isFull { get; set; }
    public int due { get; set; }
}
```

**FlatManagement Model**

```
public class FlatManagement
{
    public List<BillPayCheck> BillCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How the `GET` action looks? Why don't you ignore those fields when you create the Model?

Comment: I created the model using `EF6`, I use the models on other parts of the system as well.

Comment: Show us your `Get` method. You're  probably don't fill your ViewModel

Comment: You get the error at `rentdb.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: @adricadar, no I get error at `dbRentSchedule.isRented = BillId.isRented;`

Comment: @SinOscuras Did you checked? `BillId` is null?

Comment: @SinOscuras the Model after `POST` misses some properties, and you get null reference error. Check your model in `GET` and make sure this properties has value.

Comment: It'll show null if I don't ignore `Model.BillCollection[i].isFull != "Y"` this condition from view since I need to update `isFull` field as well.

Comment: @imannemati, I created the model using `EF6` so everything is fine there. As I mentioned before, the problem is the condition `Model.BillCollection[i].isFull != "Y"` from the view, if I remove that then it works but I can't remove that or atleast I need a workaround way.

Comment: @SinOscuras so isFull is not binding with the model..its giving null..check your get function correctly and check all records has isFull value...

Comment: @SinOscuras just give an outer if (Model.BillCollection[i].isFull != null) and run the view..If it is working fine then sure isFull is getting null somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

Add both these conditions in the linq where you are filling the BillCollection object

```
Model.BillCollection[i].fullname != "N/A" && Model.BillCollection[i].isFull != "Y"
```

Your linq should be like

```
db.BillCollection.Where(p => !p.fullname.equals("N/A") && !p.isFull.equals("Y"))
```

Comment: Still not working. I need to update `isFull` field as well. Unless I ignore `isFull` field for updating it won't work.